# NativeBase CardItem Text out of place?

Tags: user-interface, react-native, native-base

I am using react-native + mobx + nativebase. I am iterating over an array of objects. I am using [NativeBase Card component](https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#card-def-headref). I have problem with the UI going out of place. See below:

[image: hamburger overflow]

Note "Hamburgers" looks funky. I figured out this is caused by the length of the word "Hamburgers". When I shorten it to "Burgers", it looks fine. See below:

[image: burger not overflow]

This is the code. Note: recipeStore.categories is an array of object.

```
{ recipeStore.categories.map((category, index) => {
              return (
                <View key={index} style={{width: '33.3%', height: 300, padding: 20}}>
                  <Card>
                    <CardItem cardBody>
                      <Image
                        style={{width: '100%', height: 200}}
                        source={{uri: category.image}}
                      />
                      </CardItem>
                      <CardItem button onPress={() => navigate('RecipeDetailScreen', { recipe: category.recipes[0] })}>
                        <Left>
                          <Ionicons name={category.icon} style={{fontSize: 25}}/>
                        </Left>
                        <Right>
                          <Text>{ category.name }</Text>
                        </Right>  
                      </CardItem>
                    </Card>
                  </View>
```

I will need to anticipate for even longer word in the future as well. If I get a menu that is longer, I don't mind having it to overflow to next line. Something like below:

[image: appetizers overflow]

How can I make my card to handle overflow of long words?

Comment: do you have any duplicate repo for us to test?

Comment: Sorry, it is a private project. Do you have any idea how to approach it, though?

Comment: I am working on similar project, i will post you my approach to this problem :) cheers

Comment: Awesome. Thanks @GaneshCauda. Likewise I will post an Answer if I figure it out before you!

Answer (score 1):

Haven't replicated exactly what you have but the following could work. 
In the `<CardItem footer>` the `<Left>` and `<Right>` will by default take up equal space.
Use the **flex** property to allow `<Right>` to be wider than `<Left>`

```
   <CardItem footer style={{flex:4}}>
        <Left style={{flex:1}}>
           <Ionicons name="ios-microphone"/>
        </Left>
        <Right style={{flex:3}}>
          <Text>Hamburgerrrrsssssssss</Text>
        </Right>
   </CardItem>
```